# How to uninstall one ubuntu partition from a dual boot ubuntu system?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a HP ENVY 15 j037-el with Ubuntu 15.04 installed alongside Ubuntu 16.10. I would like to delete the 15.04 partition without risking to break the booting process: that happened me once and I wouldn't like to repeat the dreadful experience of fixing the grub via command line again.

The partitions I can see with `disks` are:

1. /dev/sda1, EFI system, FAT32, size 537 MB
2. /dev/sda4, root linux partition (x86_64), Ext4 (v 1.0), size 730 GB
3. /dev/sda2, linux filesystem, Ext4 (v 1.0), size 257 GB
4. /dev/sda3, Swap linux, Swap (v 1), 13 GB

Ubuntu 15.04 is installed on /dev/sda4 and Ubuntu 16.10 on /dev/sda2. 
Thank you for your help.

Edit: I already followed the instructions given for question [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on), specifically the part about the OS-Uninstaller, but as I already wrote, I had to manually fix the grub to get my laptop to boot again. I would like to know how I can safely remove the partition without risking to compromise boot.

Comment: Excuse me, but I am not asking how to completely wipe out Ubuntu in order to use Windows. I am asking how to safely remove one Ubuntu partition without compromising the functioning of the other one. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you run the `disks` command? On your `16.10` or `15.10`?

Comment: I run it from 16.10

Comment: Check /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg. It should refer to the newer install by UUID and grub device like hd0,gpt2. `cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` If not allowed to view, it may still have permissions set in fstab to 0077. You then can use live installer to view or change permissions. Boot-Repair auto changes permissions as it has to edit ESP - efi system partition.